# Get KeyEvent from a String

Tags: java

I have a method to create a toolBar for my project. I use the for-each to add tools from DrawingToolAction array to my toolBar. 
The DrawingToolAction holds 4 different objects include: Pencil, Line, Rectangle, Ellipse.

I need to add the KeyEvent for those object in my for-each loop. But I don't really know how to do that. I was thinking about String.charAt(0) but it didn't work out. Please help

```
private JToolBar createToolBar() {
    final JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();

    for (final DrawingToolAction a : myDrawingToolAction) {
        final JToggleButton tButton = new JToggleButton(a);
        final String name = tButton.getText().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(name);
        tButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("images//" + name + "_bw.gif"));
        toolBar.add(tButton);
        myDrawingToolGroup.add(tButton);
    }
    return toolBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't, really.  If anything, you might use Key Bindings, but then you should be using the [Action API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

This could mean that your `DrawingToolAction` could actual be an `Action` which carried with it all the information needed to configure it as a button and key binding in a single class

You could try using the [`setMnemonic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic(char)) property of the button

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details